# Applying a formula to Get From Web URL with VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find a way to apply a formula to a get data from web url.

So the url will look like:

http://www.thisurl.com/**formula**/restOfTheUrl

I'm new to this, so I tried recording the macro using the Advanced Get From Web function and breaking out the elements of the URL from there and substituting the formula in.

So the section of the code looked like this

```
Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents(""http://www.thisurl.com/"" & text(0.123456,2) & ""/restOfTheUrl""))
```

Had it worked, the number 2 would have been substituted in place of text(0.123456,2).

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You need to close the URL string when `& text() &`...should be like this: `...Web.Contents(""http://www.thisurl.com/"" & text(0.123456,2) & ""restOfTheUrl""))`  (Or just use a single set of quotes, if you don't need two.)

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake writing the example.  I'll edit it.  I did close out the first and last set of the URL with double quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents("http://www.thisurl.com/" & mid("0.123456", 4, 1) & "/restOfTheUrl"))
'possibly (your sample contradicts your code)
Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents("http://www.thisurl.com/" & mid("0.123456", 4, 1) & "restOfTheUrl"))
```

Comment: The quotation marks in the mid formula give a syntax error.  When I remove the quotation marks, I get the same error I got before:

Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error